# Determine the matrices that represent the following rotations of $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, rotations, orthogonal-matrices

> I need to determine the matrix that represents the following rotation of $\mathbb{R}^3$.
>
> (a) angle $\theta$, the axis $e_2$
>
> (b) angle $2\pi/3$, axis contains the vector $(1,1,1)^t$
>
> (c) angle $\pi/2$, axis contains the vector $(1,1,0)^t$

Now, I would like to check if I got the right answers because this problem has been quite difficult for me. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Please forgive me for skipping the work because formatting matrices is a real pain. Especially when I have a lot of them.

For part $(a)$, I got that $(e_2,e_3,e_1)$ is an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$. Then after simplification, the matrix is

$$\left(
        \begin{matrix}
        \cos\theta & 0 & \sin\theta \\
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        -\sin\theta & 0 & \cos\theta \\
        \end{matrix}\right)
$$

For part $(b)$, I got an orthonormal basis as $\{\left[1/\sqrt{3}, 1/\sqrt{3}, 1/\sqrt{3}\right]^t, \left[1/\sqrt{2},-1/\sqrt{2},0\right]^t,\left[1/\sqrt{6},1/\sqrt{6},-2/\sqrt{6}\right]^t\}$.

Then after simplification, the matrix is

$$\left(
        \begin{matrix}
        -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & 0 & -\frac12 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        \frac12 & 0 & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \\
        \end{matrix}\right)
$$

Is what I have done so far correct such that I can proceed with part $(c)$?

Comment: Have you included the entire question here?  When you say "angle $\theta$, the axis $e_2$", those are a scalar and vector quantity, not a boolean characteristic of the new matrix.

Comment: Um, this is what my textbook Algebra by Artin says. I have copied the question properly.

Comment: Perhaps you mean "rotate the axis vector by a certain angle"...even then it's ambiguous which direction to go.  This question really can't be answered without more context, it's hard to believe that you aren't overlooking more information about the problem being available.

Comment: yes, rotate the axis by a certain angle, counterclockwise. Is that enough added context?

Comment: You could either "rotate around an axis counterclockwise" or "rotate an axis in infinitely many possible directions".  I find the first possibility more likely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean to rotate by $\theta$ around an axis $u$, and $u$ is a unit vector, then the [general formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) is:

$R = \begin{bmatrix} \cos \theta +u_x^2 \left(1-\cos \theta\right) & u_x u_y \left(1-\cos \theta\right) - u_z \sin \theta & u_x u_z \left(1-\cos \theta\right) + u_y \sin \theta \\ u_y u_x \left(1-\cos \theta\right) + u_z \sin \theta & \cos \theta + u_y^2\left(1-\cos \theta\right) & u_y u_z \left(1-\cos \theta\right) - u_x \sin \theta \\ u_z u_x \left(1-\cos \theta\right) - u_y \sin \theta & u_z u_y \left(1-\cos \theta\right) + u_x \sin \theta & \cos \theta + u_z^2\left(1-\cos \theta\right) 
\end{bmatrix}$

Answer (score 1):

A simple check is to calculate the trace and det of the matrix obtained, since Artin's Corollary 5.1.28 states that

> Let $M$ be the matrix in $SO_3$ that represents the rotation $\rho (u, \, \alpha)$ with spin $(u, \alpha)$, then [among other things]  the trace of $M$ is $1+2 \cos\alpha$.

Now clearly you made some mistake: the desired matrix should have trace $=1+2\cos 2\pi/3=0$ and the said det. But your end matrix fails both.

the matrix $M$ turns out to be quite elegant:
$$\left[
\begin{matrix} 0 &0 &1\\1 &0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 &0\\ 
\end{matrix} \right]$$

after some calculation, i.e. with your orthonormal basis and the well-known basechange formula by conjugation, so I omit the details.

Note only that, since the basis is orthonormal, the basechange matrix $P$ (w.r.t the standard basis $E$) formed by collecting the unit (column) vectors in the basis is orthogonal, which means its inverse is readily given: $P^{-1}=P^t$

But what imo seems wanting in the procedure is something else, namely that no caution was paid as to whether the seemingly random choice of a (albeit orthonormal) basis $(u_1, u_2, u_3)$ guarantees  right-handedness, for, with $u_1$ being the unit vector along the axis of rotation, $u_2$ and $u_3$  may well be such that the system is left-handed, in which case the matrix becomes

$$M^\prime =\left[
\begin{matrix} 0 &1 &0\\0 &0 & 1\\ 1 & 0 &0\\ 
\end{matrix} \right]$$

we see that $M^\prime$ also passes both tests above, but that seems to be due to cosine’s evenness, left multiplication by $M^\prime$ sends $e_1=(1,0,0)^t$ to $e_3=(0,0,1)^t$, the angle ($\le \pi$), measured in a right-handed system and w.r.t the given axis, is obviously negative.

(To ensure right-handedness - quite intuitively- the triple product $u_1  \cdot (u_2 \times u_3)$ should be positive.)